# Synthesizable VHDL recursion, Vivado: simulator has terminated in an unexpected manner

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado, synthesis

I would like to implement a [count min sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch) with minimal update and access times.

Basically an input sample is hashed by multiple `(d)` hash functions and each of them increments a counter in the bucket that it hits. When querying for a sample, the counters of all the buckets corresponding to a sample are compared and the value of the smallest counter is returned as a result.

I am trying to find the minimum value of the counters in `log_2(d)` time with the following code:

```
entity main is
Port (    rst : in STD_LOGIC;
          a_val : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
          b_val : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
          output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
             .                               .
             .                               .
             .                               .
          CM_read_ready : out STD_LOGIC;
          clk : in STD_LOGIC);
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is

    impure function min( LB, UB: in integer; sample: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(long_length downto 0)) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is
        variable left : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(long_length downto 0) := (others=>'0');
        variable right : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(long_length downto 0) := (others=>'0');

    begin

        if (LB < UB)
        then
            left := min(LB, ((LB + UB) / 2) - 1, sample);
            right := min(((LB + UB) / 2) - 1, UB, sample);

            if (to_integer(unsigned(left)) < to_integer(unsigned(right)))
            then
                return left;
            else
                return right;
            end if;
        elsif (LB = UB)
        then
            -- return the counter's value so that it can be compared further up in the stack.
            return CM(LB, (to_integer(unsigned(hasha(LB)))*to_integer(unsigned(sample)) 
                            + to_integer(unsigned(hashb(LB)))) mod width);
        end if;
    end min;

begin

    CM_hashes_read_log_time: process (clk, rst)
    begin
        if (to_integer(unsigned(instruction)) = 2)
            then
                output <= min(0, depth - 1, sample);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

When I run the above code, I get the following errors:

> The simulator has terminated in an unexpected manner.  Please review
>   the simulation log (xsim.log) for details.
>
> [USF-XSim-62] 'compile' step failed with error(s). Please check the
>   Tcl console output or '/home/...sim/sim_1/behav/xsim/xvhdl.log' file
>   for more information.
>
> [USF-XSim-62] 'elaborate' step failed with error(s). Please check the
>   Tcl console output or
>   '/home/...sim/sim_1/synth/func/xsim/elaborate.log' file for more
>   information.

I was not able to find any file called `xsim.log` and `xvhdl.log` was empty, but `elaborate.log` had some content:

```
Vivado Simulator 2018.2
Copyright 1986-1999, 2001-2018 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Running: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2018.2/bin/unwrapped/lnx64.o/xelab -wto c199c4c74e8c44ef826c0ba56222b7cf --incr --debug typical --relax --mt 8 -L xil_defaultlib -L secureip --snapshot main_tb_behav xil_defaultlib.main_tb -log elaborate.log 
Using 8 slave threads.
Starting static elaboration
Completed static elaboration
INFO: [XSIM 43-4323] No Change in HDL. Linking previously generated obj files to create kernel
```

Removing the following line solves the above errors:

```
output <= min(0, depth - 1, sample);
```

My questions:

- Why am I not able to simulate this code?
- Will this code be synthsizable once it is working?
- Is there a better (and/or faster) way to obtain the minimum of all relevant hash buckets?

Comment: Various things wrong. `sample` and `depth` do not exist as a signal/variable in the code, so cannot be passed to min function. Process has clock and reset in sensitivity list, but are not used in the process (so this is NOT a synchronous process), `long_length` does not exist. `hasha` and `hashb` do not exist. Please provide a MCVE

Comment: Recursion is generally not recommended for synthesis as it can be unclear what the circuit intent is. Especially not when the recursion is a function with no possibility of pipelining.

Comment: Problem that is likely "the" problem: your function `min` does not always return a value -- there is no `else` clause to handle the `LB > UB` case. This is almost certainly why the code will not compile. Problem that is also "a" problem: your function `min` should not be `impure`. See this reference which describes the differences between pure and impure functions in VHDL: https://vhdlwhiz.com/function/

Comment: ...but as @Tricky has pointed out, once you've fixed the `min` function you'll still have problems. I expect that your code will compile at that point, but it will still not work like you expected (your `CM_hashes_read_log_time` process will not have the timing behavior you wanted) due to other problems in the code.

Comment: You couldn't possibly have 'run the above code'; it's full of bugs. Post something that at least compiles, and *then* fails in elaboration or at runtime. In other words, xvhdl, at least, must complete without errors.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I produced a lot of bugs while trying to make the code minimal. I no longer need the function because I am generating HDL code with a python script, but I would still like to follow up on recursion. Should I delete my question and re-post it when I have a MCVE?

Comment: If you just want to know about recursion: in general, it's fine for *synthesis* if your function runs during the synthesis equivalent of *elaboration*. In other words, it has to be part of model setup; you could use it to set the contents of a ROM, for example. All bets are off if it is required to turn into real gates, though. It's unlikely that any synthesiser could cope with even a trivial recursive hardware structure, but I'm prepared to be surprised.

Comment: @EML: see answer below (just to surprise you) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not that I was able to find any real world use for recursion, but just to surprise  @EML (as requested in the comments above): you actually **can** define recursive hardware structures in VHDL.

In Quartus at least, this only works if you give the compiler a clear indication of the maximum recursion depth, otherwise it will try to unroll the recursion to any possible input, eventually dying from a stack overflow:

```
entity recursive is
    generic
    (
        MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH  : natural
    );
    port
    (
        clk     : in std_ulogic;
        n       : in natural;
        o       : out natural
    );
end recursive;

architecture Behavioral of recursive is
    function fib(max_depth : natural; n : natural) return natural is
        variable res : natural;
    begin
        if max_depth <= 1 then
            res := 0;
            return res;
        end if;
        if n = 0 then
            res := 0;
        elsif n = 1 or n = 2 then
            res := 1;
        else
            res := fib(max_depth - 1, n - 1) + fib(max_depth - 1, n - 2);
        end if;
        return res;
    end function fib;
begin
    p_calc : process
    begin
        wait until rising_edge(clk);
        o <= fib(MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH, n); 
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

With a `MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH` of 6, this generates one single combinational circuit with more than 500 LEs (so the pracical use is probably **very** limited), but at least it works.

Comment: [Recursion in structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981526/declare-a-variable-number-of-signals-with-variable-bitwidth-in-vhdl93/50002251#50002251) can also be synthesis eligible usin generic constants to bound 'depth' in addition to recursive function calls with bounded depth.

Comment: @user1155120 cudos for the linked answer, it's a smart one. Unfortunately, Quartus II isn't smart enough to compile it (as it does not allow generics to refer to other generics in the same interface list).

Comment: There's your problem. As noted in the answer there are two features only available in -2008 and Quartus II  is not compatible. Note the OP's question here mentions Vivado.

Comment: Yup, surprised...:)

Answer (score 0):

Is recursion possible in VHDL?

I would say, yes, but not recursion as we know it. That's the short answer. I have code (if anyone is interested that implements Quicksort) and it will synthesize quite happily. If anyone knows about Quicksort, it normally won't be anywhere near the context of synthesis. But I managed to do it.

The trick (which is vexatious and hard to follow) is to emulate recursion with a strange state machine that backtracks to the beginning state, after pushing a "state" onto a (hardware) stack. You can synthesize this sort of data structure quite easily if you want.

I recall some fascinating stuff written by Thatcher, Goguen and Wright about semantic transformations from one kind of coding domain to others (different models of computation, in short).

It does strike me that this is possibly a genesis point for actual recursive expressions in a more general sense. But do be warned, it's very difficult.