# Width mismatch in assignment: VHDL

Tags: vhdl

My code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library work;
use work.costanti.all;

entity Multiplier is
    generic(nbA:integer:=nbA;
            nbB:integer:=nbB);
    port (
        A: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbA-1 downto 0);
        B: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbB-1 downto 0);
        clk: in STD_LOGIC;
        R: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbA+nbB-1 downto 0));

end Multiplier;

architecture Behavioral of Multiplier is

component AdderTree is
    generic(nbit: integer:=nbA+nbB);
    port (
          IN1: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          IN2: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          IN3: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          IN4: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          IN5: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          IN6: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          IN7: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          IN8: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          IN9: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0);
          S: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbit-1 downto 0)
          );
end component;

signal V : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbA-1 downto 0);
signal P : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((nbA*nbB)-1 downto 0);
signal PP_0to6 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( (nbA)+(nbA+1)+(nbA+2)+(nbA+3)+(nbA+4)+(nbA+5)+(nbA+6)-1 downto 0); --(dim(pp0+PP1+PP2+PP3+PP4+PP5+PP6) downto 0 )
signal PP7 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbA+nbB-1 downto 0);
signal P7 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nbA downto 0);
signal PPP : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((nbA+nbB)*(nbB+1)-1 downto 0);


begin

for_g: for i in 0 to nbB-1 generate
        V <= (others => B(i));
        P((nbB)*(i)+(nbB-1) downto (nbB)*(i)) <= V and A;
end generate for_g;

P7 <= '0' & P((nbA*nbB)-1 downto (nbA*nbB)-1-(nbB-1));

PP_0to6(nbB-1 downto 0)  <= P(nbB-1 downto 0); --PP0

for_g2: for i in 0 to nbB-3 generate
         PP_0to6((nbB+1)*(i+1)+(i*(i+1)/2)+7 downto (nbB+1)*(i+1)+(i*(i+1)/2)) <= P(nbB*(i+1)+(nbB-1) downto nbB*(i+1)); --PP1 to PP6
         PP_0to6((nbB+1)*(i+1)+(i*(i+1)/2)-1 downto (nbB+1)*(i)+((i-1)*(i)/2)+7+1) <= (others => '0');
end generate for_g2;

PP7(nbA+nbB-1 downto nbA-1) <= P7;
PP7(nbA-2 downto 0) <= (others => '0');

PPP_0to6: for i in 3 to nbB-2 generate
            PPP(((i+1)*(nbA+nbB-1)+i)-(8-i) downto i*(nbA+nbB)) <= PP_0to6( (i+1)*(nbB-1)+((1/2)*((i*i)+(3*i))) downto i*(nbB)+(i-1)*i/2); --PP0 to PP6
            PPP(((i+1)*(nbA+nbB-1)+i) downto ((i+1)*(nbA+nbB-1)+i)-(8-i)+1)<= (others => '0');
end generate PPP_0to6;

-- Fill last 32 bits of PPP
--Insert ADDER TREE
 
end Behavioral;
```

Portion of the error code: [portion of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy2H4.png)

```
PPP_0to6: for i in 0 to nbB-2 generate

        PPP(((i+1)*(nbA+nbB-1)+i)-(8-i) downto i*(nbA+nbB)) <= PP_0to6( (i+1)*(nbB-1)+((1/2)*((i*i)+(3*i))) downto i*(nbB)+(i-1)*i/2); --PP0 to PP6

        PPP(((i+1)*(nbA+nbB-1)+i) downto ((i+1)*(nbA+nbB-1)+i)-(8-i)+1)<= (others => '0');

end generate PPP_0to6;
```

Hi, I'm making a multiplier on vhdl, but on line 66 it reports me the following error:

if i=1: [Synth 8-690] width mismatch in assignment; target has 9 bits, source has 7 bits ["...Multiplier.vhd":66]

if i=2: [Synth 8-690] width mismatch in assignment; target has 10 bits, source has 5 bits ["...Multiplier.vhd":66]

if i=3: [Synth 8-690] width mismatch in assignment; target has 11 bits, source has 2 bits ["...Multiplier.vhd":66]

and so on..

I can't understand why, they seem to be the same size ..

my constant are:

nbA=8
nbB=8

and the signal P, PP_0to6 and PPP:

```
signal P : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((nbA*nbB)-1 downto 0);
signal PP_0to6 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( (nbA)+(nbA+1)+(nbA+2)+(nbA+3)+(nbA+4)+(nbA+5)+(nbA+6)-1 downto 0);
signal PPP : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((nbA+nbB)*(nbB+1)-1 downto 0);
```

N.B. I make sure to shift to the rigth by adding zeros as in the figure:

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAH47.jpg)

The error is here:

```
PPP(((i+1)*(nbA+nbB-1)+i)-(8-i) downto i*(nbA+nbB)) <= PP_0to6( (i+1)*(nbB-1)+((1/2)*((i*i)+(3*i))) downto i*(nbB)+(i-1)*i/2);
```

but if I tried to replace the value of i:

```
i=0: PPP(7 downto 0) <= PP_0to6(7 downto 0);
i=1: PPP(24 downto 16)<=PP_0to6(16 downto 8)
i=2: PPP(41 downto 32)<=PP_0to6(26 downto 17)
i=3: PPP(58 downto 48)<=PP_0to6(37 downto 27)
...
...
```

the dimensions look the same.

Comment: Please don't post code as images, that makes it impossible for anyone to copy your code to try and fix it.

Comment: I demonstrated a [VHDL adder tree with recursive instantiation in generate statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981526/declare-a-variable-number-of-signals-with-variable-bitwidth-in-vhdl93/50002251#50002251) a little more than 2 1/2 years ago. I used report statements to get the bounds right. You'd likely see the issue of you reported left and right bounds of each generated block. Provide a [mcve], simulate and show us those errors.

Comment: It seems to me you're making your life (and whoever else gets to see this code) very hard by stuffing everything in one gigantic signal. The code would be much more readable and less error prone if you model it more after the drawing you posted. I.e. instead of `PP_0to6` create an array `PP` with 7 elements (same for `P` and `PPP`). I'm willing to bet that debugging that is going to be much much easier.

Comment: @Darhuuk thank you, I know that it is the best solution. I wanted to use for generate for educational purposes and for this I had created a unique array. But you are right, indeed the code as you say is more readable. So as it also says in the figure, I create multiple arrays PP1, PP2, PP3 ... and so for PPP?

Comment: @MarcoGreco I wouldn't create multiple signals `PP1, PP2, ...`. Create an actual array, i.e. `PP(0), PP(1), ...`. That way you can still use the generate block and do calculations which depend on the index you're generating logic for. E.g. for element 0 of `PP` you add 0 zeros at the LSB, for element 1 you add 1 zero element, etc. For the MSB side the number of zeros to add is then `8 - index`. (Based on the schematic.)

Comment: Use asserts to log both the value of those unreadable expressions, and what you think the values ought to be. Tracedown any discrepancies and fix the mistakes. And simplify your style : you can write and use functions to avoid complex repetitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess strictly speaking this answer doesn't really answer your question, since I'm not trying to figure out where your error is. But I'm convinced that if you change your coding style you won't encounter such difficult to debug errors any more.

As mentioned in my comments, your code will become must clearer and easier to debug if you split the signal up properly. I.e. don't create one giant signal for everything.

VHDL has arrays and records, use them, they won't make your circuit any larger, but the code will be much easier to reason about.

It's been a while since I actually wrote VHDL, so the syntax below might contain typo's, but hopefully the idea behind the code is clear:

```
constant c_AllZeros : std_logic_vector(c_MaxZeros - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');

...

type t_P is std_logic_vector(c_SomeLength - 1 downto 0);
subtype t_P_Array is array (natural range <>) of t_P;

...

signal P : t_P_Array(0 to c_NumInputs - 1);

...

PPP_0to6: for i in PPP'range generate
  PP(i)  <= P(i) & c_AllZeros(index downto 0);
  PPP(i) <= c_AllZeros(c_MaxZeros - index downto 0) & PP(i);
end generate PPP_0to6;
```

As you might notice, I also got rid of the explicit indices for the for-loop in the `generate`. There's still a magic number when indexing the `all_zeroes` signal to generate `PPP`. If I was writing this code, I'd replace that with some (calculated) constant with a meaningful name. This will make the code both more readable and trivial to change later on.

Note that there's other ways to do this. E.g. you could first set all bits of all `PP` signals to 0 and then assign a slice of them the `P` value.

Comment: you are right, maybe I should have specified how I chose to use these indexes (which I would have done in the report of this project). I thought the problem was with the syntax of vhdl. Thank you for the alternative solutions. They make the code much more readable and simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, the vhdl course I took at the university is of few credits and we have not dealt with several constructs in detail. Your solution helped me personally, as the teacher does not accept constructs not taught during the course. In the end I used a solution that was not flexible (on the other hand the track did not require it) but correct. Thank you, for personal projects I will certainly use your solution.

Comment: @MarcoGreco Ah, I always find it sad to hear about teachers/professors not allowing objectively better solutions. Either way, great to hear you figured it out. If I had to use a solution such as the one required by your professor, I would have calculated constants all the bits offsets, and assigned that way. I.e. something like `c_PP0_LSB = 0`, `c_PP1_LSB = c_PP0_LSB + c_PP_Width`, etc.